# what's a flood-color and lighting-color definition in CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg-filters

Way cool, i'd just realised there is something called `flood-color` and `lighting-color` in CSS. Does anyone know what is a `flood-color` and `lighting-color` and what do they do?

What exactly do these mean?:

> The ‘flood-color’ property indicates what color to use to flood the
>   current filter primitive subregion. The keyword currentColor and ICC
>   colors can be specified in the same manner as within a 
>   specification for the ‘fill’ and ‘stroke’ properties.
>
> The ‘lighting-color’ property defines the color of the light source
>   for filter primitives ‘feDiffuseLighting’ and ‘feSpecularLighting’.

How do we apply these so-called *SVG* effects? I've tried setting the lighting-color to red but there doesn't seem to be any effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are SVG filter effects.

> The ‘lighting-color’ property defines the color of the light source
>   for filter primitives ‘feDiffuseLighting’ and ‘feSpecularLighting’.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#LightingColorProperty

> The ‘flood-opacity’ property defines the opacity value to use across
>   the entire filter primitive subregion.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FloodColorProperty

Comment: do they work like the SVG effects of background gradients? or rather how exactly do we apply it? i've tried setting them to different valid color values  but none of it is showing any forms of differences

Answer (score 3):

The spec wasn't very helpful when I looked this up.
Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content

> There are three styles you may apply: you may use mask, clip-path, or filter.

The only time I've ever needed to use this was when I wanted to invert graphics using XOR.

Define the SVG filter:

```
<svg>
    <filter id="xor" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <feFlood flood-color="#ff1493" result="flood"/>
        <feComposite operator="xor" in="SourceAlpha" in2="flood"/>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Apply using CSS:

```
<style>
    .stylename{
        mask: url(#xor);
    }
</style>
```